# Plugins - Could not load file or assembly 'MyPlugins.Extensions

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Many reactions concerning this topic can be found on the Stack-Overflow and the rest of the Internet, a solution however I did not find.

I have an assembly (MyPlugins.Plugins) containing all the plug-ins I use in CRM2011. This assembly references 2 other assemblies namely MyPlugins.Helpers and MyPlugins.Extensions. The last assembly has only one file (extensions.cs).

All assemblies are stored in the server/assembly/bin directory (as always) and properly registered with the plugin-registration tool.

After I made changes to the extensions assembly, my troubles started.

For some reason the program can not find the extensions assembly. I have tried many things here including un-register the assembly and register again, stored it in the database and back on disk.

At the end I removed the MyPlugins.Extensions from the project and from disk and added the extensions.cs to the remaining projects and did a rebuild of the solution.

Strange enough I get exact the same error message although all references to the extensions plugin  as well as the assembly are removed. It looks like if the old references are not replaced with the new ones.

Can anyone help me out here?

Regards,
Martin

Comment: There might be a version conflict. Deploy the assemblies. Do IIS reset and redeploy the plugins again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but done that. I'm developing on a virtual machine (VirtualBox latest version). Have restarted everything possible (services, app-pools, iis, the lot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the old version of the plugins may be getting cached by IIS. Two things to try:

1. (Hack) IISReset on all front-end CRM servers.
2. (Recommended) Increment the minor build number of your assembly and re-register. When you increment the build number, all front-end servers reload the assembly into cache.

Comment: Thanks Josh, incrementing the assemblies rebuilding and re-registering solved my problems.

Comment: I also did the same almost a year ago. Was scratching my head to remind myself what I did to fix the problem. @Josh thanks for reminding me.